# How to create an API secured by api key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a *RESTful* API using [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and I'm unable to secure it with access key, How can I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JWT Authentication](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/12/19/how-to-use-jwt-authentication-with-django-rest-framework.html) to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you can use built-in Django Rest Framework token authentication, as stated [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication), this will create non-expiring tokens in database that can be used as API keys in your case. However, if you don't want to store them at database and set your custom expiration periods for your tokens, I suggest you using [simplejwt](https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt) library for Django Rest Framework